# Index running over wrong interval

Tags: c++, indexing

I cannot figure out why this is happening. ngrid is going to be some multiple of 10. For ngrid = 10 say, when I print out 0.7*ngrid I get 7, which is of course correct. But when I print out I it prints out 6 as well as 7 & 8. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

```
    for(int i=(0.7*ngrid); i<0.8*ngrid; i++)
    {
    cout << i;
    operator()(0.2*ngrid,i) = -3.0;
    }
```

ngrid is type int and is declared in the constructor

```
class Field
{
  private:
    double* data;
    int     n;
    int index(int x, int y) const { return x + (n+1)*y; }
  public:


    Field(int ngrid)  : n(ngrid)
    {
      data = new double[(ngrid+1)*(ngrid+1)];
      int l=(ngrid+1)*(ngrid+1);
      for (int i=0;i<l;i++) data[i]=0.0;
    }
```

Comment: Which type is `ngrid`, where is declared and how is it initialized? Please add this to the question.

Comment: you are not showing how you initialize `ngrid` of your first snippet. The `ngrid` in your second snippets is just the parameter passed to the constructor. It has local scope. Its not clear how the two code snippets are related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing a few dangerous things here. First of all, expecting the result of a float operation to come out to an exact integer.  It turns out that even if `ngrid` is of type `int`, 0.7 is *not* representable in IEEE floating-point format. You can see if you use [this page](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that 0.7 is actually represented as 0.699999988079071. Multiply by 10 and then cast that to an `int`, and now you have 6.

Similarly, 0.8 is represented as 0.800000011920929. So when 8 is compared to 8.00000011920929, it is correctly determined to still be less, and so 8 is printed as well.

So when your `for` loop starts executing, `i` is initialized as 6 rather than 7. That's why 6 is printed out. The moral of the story is, don't expect floating point arithmetic to work out nicely to an integer... even if you are only dealing with one decimal place. The computer doesn't work with base 10 numbers, so not everything is as easily representable.

Instead of doing float arithmetic (assuming `ngrid` is an `int`), multiply it by 7 and then divide by 7. This will do integer arithmetic instead of floating-point arithmetic. Since you said `ngrid` is always a multiple of 10, the result should always be an integer and you won't have to worry about truncation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix integers and floats/doubles. `for` is only for array indexes, or other integer walktrhru. Use `while`.

Or, use fixpoint, multiply everything with, say, 100.

**Edit:** When programmers find a `for` in the code, they thinks, "it's a kind of walkthru on indexes, or integer coordinates". If you have such a problem, like break out of the loop when x * 0.7 reaches a level, it's better to use `while`, it means "we're repeating something, until certain condution occurs". Some languages don't even allow using non-integers in `for`.

Comment: `for` has no such limitation.

Comment: Yep, but `for` is for cases, where the elements are, err, I don't know the correct math term for it, *countable*. Anyway, you're right, `for` is just an expression form of a "base value, increment, exit condition" cycle.

Answer (score 0):

my modest opinion:

change 0.7*ngrid to (7*ngrid)/10 and 0.8*ngrid to (8*ngrid )/10

so you have only integers

int i=0.7*ngrid casts ngrid to float/double due to 0.7 then you cast again to int as i is delared integer rounding the product to the lower integer.